# Can I say "the door is open by me"?

Tags: passive-voice

Can I change the active voice **"I open the door"** to passive voice:

**"The door is open by me"?**

Or is it:

**"The door is opened by me"?**

Comment: You can use your second example, but it's awkward. Your third example also changes to past tense on "open", so it should "was" not "is". However, I'm not sure why you'd say it any of these ways... open is well... open and shut. Either you *will* open the door (future tense), or you already opened the door (past tense). I'm not sure why you'd ever say it in present tense.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your answer. Now let me explain this to you that was a question in an exam I had and it was about to change active voice to pasaive voice "I open the door" to pasaive voice I think I open the door is in general

Comment: Ah... That makes more sense. I'm vaguely surprised that they couldn't come up with a smoother sounding question for an exam.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct. According to [this](http://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Green%20Level/G4%20Past%20Passive.html), passive voice is used by combining "**is**" with the **past participle** of the verb. Depending on tense, they will also be combined with extra words, such as "be", "have", etc. The tense of "**is**" determines the tense of the sentence:

> - The door **is opened** by me (present)
> - The door **was opened** by me (past)
> - The door **will *be* opened** by me (future)
> - The door **is *going to be* opened** by me (future)
> - The door **has *been* opened** by me (present perfect)
> - The door **would *have been*** opened by me (conditional perfect)
> - The door **will *have been*** opened by me (future perfect)

Comment: So according to your answer my third example is correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You changed the question, but I was saying "the door is open by me" and "the door opened by me" are wrong. I'll change my answer

Answer (score -1):

This is a imperative sentence and there is given order.  So,  we write in passive voice
"you are ordered to open the door"
Or
"let the door be opened"

Comment: It is not an imperative sentence. The sentence that the OP is trying to passivise is a perfectly normal simple present indicative.